# Show downloadable link to csv

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I am trying to show a stream of data in a downloadable .csv file with the following code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                    byte[] csvBytes = wc.DownloadData(url);
                    return File(csvBytes, "text/csv", "Test.csv");
```

The URL returns data in this format:

"PAUL","SMITH","A & P CONSTRUCTION","211 N JACKSON ST","New York","NY","98055"
    "JEROME","HALSEY","A A A LOCATING INC","1906 SOUTHVIEW DR","PAPILLION","NE","68046"
    "MIKE","GIBILISCO","ABSOLUTE SECURITY INC","944 S JEFFERSON ST","PAPILLION","NE","84102"

The above works well, and I get a downloadable link ... but when I open the .csv file - I get the records in just one row:

```
\"PAUL\"    \"SMITH\"   \"A & P CONSTRUCTION\"  \"211 N JACKSON ST\"    \"PAPILLION\"   \"NE\"  \"68046\"...
```

How should I modify the above code so that I get the values in the right format (without the "\" and under the right columns)?

Comment: Looks odd. Try any other browser for the same action. Or try FireFox in Private Browsing mode to disable any addons which can affect on format of the CSV

Comment: I test with firefox and IE (latest versions) but get the same results

Comment: Ok, the only reason is you're getting the wrong data in DownloadData().

To check this replace your return with
return Content(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));

And tell what you get in your browser.

Comment: "\"PAUL\",\"SMITH\",\"A & P CONSTRUCTION\",\"211 N JACKSON ST\",\"PAPILLION\",\"NE\",\"68046\"\r\n\,\"JEROME\",\"HALSEY\",\"A A A LOCATING INC\",\"1906 SOUTHVIEW DR\",\"PAPILLION\",\"NE\",\"68046\"\r\n\ ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19184/discussion-between-max-shmelev-and-dotnetnewbie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you're getting different data when you're using your `WebClient`. It seems that the server looks at HTTP headers when it builds CSV for you.

So, you need to emulate your browser as much as you can (as far as you're getting correct CSV in the browser) to make the CSV server think you're the browser. To do that you need view HTTP headers, which your browser sends when you access the CSV URL (you can do it with Fiddler, or any development tools built-in in your browser). And you need to end up with smth like this:

```
wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
```

Add the headers one by one, just be sure to have absolutely the same headers as your browser sends (and ignore headers like "cookie", "host").

Answer (score 0):

Try to change a Mime type to "application/csv".

Mime type for CSV are also these: text/comma-separated-values, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.msexcel, text/anytext

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: You could try "application/octet-stream".